# Does Foundry Scenarios support Quiver?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios

I would like to use Scenarios in my Quiver application - does Scenarios support Quiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Quiver template widget in Workshop to integrate with Scenarios. Both modified object data and timeseries will be reflected in the Quiver template widget when a Scenario is specified.